# html email table border looks different on different devices

Tags: php, html, css, email, woocommerce

I'm customising the Woocommerce email templates at the moment, and very weirdly the table border in those templates looks different on different devices.

The first photo is a capture from the mail seen on Macbook Mail app and the border appears in the way as it's supposed to.

[image]

This one is a screenshot from  from the iPhone Gmail app; the border is extremely distorted.

[image]

I couldn't attach one I took from the native iPhone Mail app but the border appears on only certain parts of the table.

Below is the code for the table.

```
<table class="td" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" style="width: 100%; font-family: ; mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important; mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important; border-spacing: 0 !important; border-collapse: collapse !important; table-layout: auto; margin: 0 auto !important; color: #333333; border: 0.5px solid #e5e5e5;" lucida sans unicode grande sans-serif border="1">
<thead><tr>
<th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align: left; font-size: 11px; color: #333333; border: 0.5px solid #e5e5e5; padding: 12px;">Product</th>
            <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align: left; font-size: 11px; color: #333333; border: 0.5px solid #e5e5e5; padding: 12px;">Quantity</th>
            <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align: left; font-size: 11px; color: #333333; border: 0.5px solid #e5e5e5; padding: 12px;">Price</th>
        </tr></thead>
<tbody style="font-size: 11px;"><tr class="order_item">
<td class="td" style="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle; border: 1px solid #eee; font-family: ; mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important; mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important; color: #333333; padding: 12px;" lucida sans unicode grande sans-serif word-wrap:break-word>CLLR Issue
1<br><small></small>
</td>
            <td class="td" style="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle; border: 1px solid #eee; font-family: ; mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important; mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important; color: #333333; padding: 12px;" lucida sans unicode grande sans-serif>1</td>
            <td class="td" style="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle; border: 1px solid #eee; font-family: ; mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important; mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important; color: #333333; padding: 12px;" lucida sans unicode grande sans-serif><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount
amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">£</span>12.00</span></td>
        </tr></tbody>
<tfoot>
<tr>
<th class="td" scope="row" colspan="2" style="text-align: left; font-size: 11px; border-top-width: 4px; color: #333333; border: 0.5px solid #e5e5e5; padding: 12px;">Subtotal:</th>
                        <td class="td" style="text-align: left; font-size: 11px; border-top-width: 4px; mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important; mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important; color: #333333; border: 0.5px solid #e5e5e5; padding: 12px;"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount
amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">£</span>12.00</span></td>
                    </tr>
<tr>
<th class="td" scope="row" colspan="2" style="text-align: left; font-size: 11px; color: #333333; border: 0.5px solid #e5e5e5; padding: 12px;">Shipping:</th>
                        <td class="td" style="text-align: left; font-size: 11px; mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important; mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important; color: #333333; border: 0.5px solid #e5e5e5; padding: 12px;">
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">£</span>3.90</span> <small class="shipped_via">via Royal Mail 1st Class Signed for</small>
</td>
                    </tr>
<tr>
<th class="td" scope="row" colspan="2" style="text-align: left; font-size: 11px; color: #333333; border: 0.5px solid #e5e5e5; padding: 12px;">Payment Method:</th>
                        <td class="td" style="text-align: left; font-size: 11px; mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important; mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important; color: #333333; border: 0.5px solid #e5e5e5; padding: 12px;">Stripe</td>
                    </tr>
<tr>
<th class="td" scope="row" colspan="2" style="text-align: left; font-size: 11px; color: #333333; border: 0.5px solid #e5e5e5; padding: 12px;">Total:</th>
                        <td class="td" style="text-align: left; font-size: 11px; mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important; mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important; color: #333333; border: 0.5px solid #e5e5e5; padding: 12px;"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">£</span>15.90</span></td>
                    </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

And here is the CSS in the head.

```
<style type="text/css">@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 413px) { 
    .email-container {
        min-width: 375px !important;
    }
}@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
    #body_content_inner,
    h2,
    h3,
    td {
     font-size: 14px !important;
    }
}@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and
(max-device-width: 413px) { 
            .email-container {
                min-width: 375px !important;
            }
}@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
    #body_content_inner,
    h2,
    h3,
    td {
     font-size: 14px !important;
    }
}
```

What could possibly be the reason for this behaviour?

-updated:
Below is the revised code based on @Benr89 's comment. On everywhere else, the table looks fine, but on Gmail iPhone app two lines appear between in the middle of the second row [photo] (cllrart.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/IMG_4425.png)

```
<table class="td" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" style="width: 100%; font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande',
sans-serif; mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important; mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important; border: 1px solid #eee; border-spacing: 0 !important; border-collapse: collapse !important; table-layout: auto; margin: 0 auto !important; color: #333333;" border="10">
<thead><tr>
<th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align: left; font-size: 11px; color: #333333; border: 1px solid #eee; padding: 12px;">Product</th>
            <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align: left; font-size: 11px; color: #333333; border: 1px solid #eee; padding: 12px;">Quantity</th>
            <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align: left; font-size: 11px; color: #333333; border: 1px solid #eee; padding: 12px;">Price</th>
        </tr></thead>
<tbody style="font-size: 11px;"><tr class="order_item">
<td class="td" style="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle; border: 1px solid #eee; font-family: ; mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important; mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important; color: #333333; padding: 12px;" lucida sans unicode grande sans-serif word-wrap:break-word>CLLR Issue
1<br><small></small>
</td>
            <td class="td" style="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle; border: 1px solid #eee; font-family: ; mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important; mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important; color: #333333; padding: 12px;" lucida sans unicode grande sans-serif>2</td>
            <td class="td" style="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle; border: 1px solid #eee; font-family: ; mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important; mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important; color: #333333; padding: 12px;" lucida sans unicode grande sans-serif><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount
amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">£</span>24.00</span></td>
        </tr></tbody>
<tfoot>
<tr>
<th class="td" scope="row" colspan="2" style="text-align: left; font-size: 11px; border-top-width: 4px; color: #333333; border: 1px solid #eee; padding: 12px;">Subtotal:</th>
                        <td class="td" style="text-align: left; font-size: 11px; border-top-width: 4px; mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important; mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important; color: #333333; border: 1px solid #eee; padding: 12px;"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount
amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">£</span>24.00</span></td>
                    </tr>
<tr>
<th class="td" scope="row" colspan="2" style="text-align: left; font-size: 11px; color: #333333; border: 1px solid #eee; padding: 12px;">Shipping:</th>
                        <td class="td" style="text-align: left; font-size: 11px; mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important; mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important; color: #333333; border: 1px solid #eee; padding: 12px;">
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">£</span>3.90</span> <small class="shipped_via">via Royal Mail 1st Class Signed for</small>
</td>
                    </tr>
<tr>
<th class="td" scope="row" colspan="2" style="text-align: left; font-size: 11px; color: #333333; border: 1px solid #eee; padding: 12px;">Payment Method:</th>
                        <td class="td" style="text-align: left; font-size: 11px; mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important; mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important; color: #333333; border: 1px solid #eee; padding: 12px;">Stripe</td>
                    </tr>
<tr>
<th class="td" scope="row" colspan="2" style="text-align: left; font-size: 11px; color: #333333; border: 1px solid #eee; padding: 12px;">Total:</th>
                        <td class="td" style="text-align: left; font-size: 11px; mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important; mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important; color: #333333; border: 1px solid #eee; padding: 12px;"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">£</span>27.90</span></td>
                    </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: mind posting the code as well..?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile thanks for your comment. I wasn't sure which parts of the codes to upload; what would be most helpful?

Comment: upload the mailer muckup

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile I've just uploaded them. Please let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: all your styling is inline?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile just added CSS in the head. Not sure if it's relevant, though.

Comment: the last time I checked gmail did not support `<style>` tag u needed to put css inline.  but they had plans to support it not sure f they do  now havent done mailers in a while

Answer (score 0):

First of all, set border="0" in your opening table.

Your main problem is that you are using 0.5px as a border size on some of your table cells. Change these to 1px and your borders are fine.

I have added your new code below, I have tested in Litmus and all works fine :)

EDIT - NEW CODE ADDED BELOW-------------------------------------------------

Ok for some reason you had border="10" in your opening table, this is not valid so I have changed to 0. you had variious errors in your css. eg, empty font-family tags (you had left the value outside off the "").

I have also removed the Table head and table footer sections as they are not needed in emails at all.

Stick to using table, tr and td.(you may want to go trhough and remove your th tags aswell as they are not needed and just use td instead.)

Anyway, this should fix your email - I havent been able to test it on the gmail Iphone app as Litmus dont provide support for it. And I dont have an Iphone im an android user.

```
     <table class="td" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" style="width: 100%; font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande',
sans-serif; mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important; mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important; border: 1px solid #eee; border-spacing: 0 !important; border-collapse: collapse !important; table-layout: auto; margin: 0 auto !important; color: #333333;" border="1">
    <tbody style="font-size: 11px;">
        <tr>
            <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align: left; font-size: 11px; color: #333333; border: 1px solid #eee; padding: 12px;">Product</th>
            <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align: left; font-size: 11px; color: #333333; border: 1px solid #eee; padding: 12px;">Quantity</th>
            <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align: left; font-size: 11px; color: #333333; border: 1px solid #eee; padding: 12px;">Price</th>
        </tr>

        <tr class="order_item">
            <td class="td" style="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle; border: 1px solid #eee; font-family:lucida sans unicode grande sans-serif ; mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important; color: #333333; padding: 12px; word-wrap:break-word">
                CLLR Issue
                1<br><small></small>
            </td>
            <td class="td" style="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle; border: 1px solid #eee; font-family:'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande' ; mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important; color: #333333; padding: 12px;" lucida sans unicode grande sans-serif>2</td>
            <td class="td" style="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle; border: 1px solid #eee; font-family:'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande' ; mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important; color: #333333; padding: 12px;">
                <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount
amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">£</span>24.00</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="td" scope="row" colspan="2" style="text-align: left; font-size: 11px; border-top-width: 4px; color: #333333; border: 1px solid #eee; padding: 12px;">Subtotal:</th>
            <td class="td" style="text-align: left; font-size: 11px; border-top-width: 4px; mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important; mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important; color: #333333; border: 1px solid #eee; padding: 12px;">
                <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount
amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">£</span>24.00</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="td" scope="row" colspan="2" style="text-align: left; font-size: 11px; color: #333333; border: 1px solid #eee; padding: 12px;">Shipping:</th>
            <td class="td" style="text-align: left; font-size: 11px; mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important; mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important; color: #333333; border: 1px solid #eee; padding: 12px;">
                <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">£</span>3.90</span> <small class="shipped_via">via Royal Mail 1st Class Signed for</small>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="td" scope="row" colspan="2" style="text-align: left; font-size: 11px; color: #333333; border: 1px solid #eee; padding: 12px;">Payment Method:</th>
            <td class="td" style="text-align: left; font-size: 11px; mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important; mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important; color: #333333; border: 1px solid #eee; padding: 12px;">Stripe</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="td" scope="row" colspan="2" style="text-align: left; font-size: 11px; color: #333333; border: 1px solid #eee; padding: 12px;">Total:</th>
            <td class="td" style="text-align: left; font-size: 11px; mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important; mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important; color: #333333; border: 1px solid #eee; padding: 12px;"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">£</span>27.90</span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've changed the border size to 1px and standadised the border colour to #eee throughout. Everything else looks fine, but there still appears two lines between in the middle of the second row [photo] (http://cllrart.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/IMG_4425.png) why could it be...?

Comment: they only appear in Gmail app

Comment: Could you re-post your complete code, Im not having the same issue with mine. thanks

Comment: I've uploaded the revised code. Thank you very much. @Benr89